# vimscript - get a string consisting of multiple copies of a single char

Tags: string, vim, char

So, I would like to do something like `let dummy_string = 'a' * 6` and get `dummy_string` to contain a `aaaaaa` string.

Comment: Want a string-related function? Do `:help string-functions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`repeat()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#repeat%28%29), see `:help repeat()` for details.

```
let dummy_string = repeat('a',6)
```

Related question in [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), [vimscript: how to repeat a string N times?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14385/vimscript-how-to-repeat-a-string-n-times)